# Retrieve PDF file stored in SQL Server database and then display on page

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, pdf

I'm working on asp.net application where it display the retrieved pdf file from database on the page. I'm facing problem where the pdf file is not displaying in the page

With this I'm attaching my code that I have tried:

```
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Pdf from SavePdf where IC='" + id +   
        "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            byte[] fileData = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);

            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();                   
        }
        dr.Close(); 
       }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfect for me.Are you getting some kind of error or something?

Comment: @Ramashankar, I'm getting blank page where it's showing connecting.

Comment: Did you verified your PDF data/bytes, that you are fetching from database?

Comment: @Ramashankar,Yes. I have verified it as I tried to save to local machine and it's working fine.

Comment: Could you try the code i just posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20757786/1172862)

Comment: @Ramashankar, managed to find the solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString[&#34;id&#34;]);
            Display(id);
        }
    }

    private void Display(int id)
    {
        DataSet ds = GetData(&#34;select * from tblFiles where Id=@Id&#34;, id);
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][&#34;Data&#34;];
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = &#34;&#34;;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = &#34;application/pdf&#34;;
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    private DataSet GetData(string query, int id)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[&#34;constr_files&#34;].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(&#34;@Id&#34;, id);
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works perfect for me.

```
protected void ShowPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] fileData = GetPdfBytes(); 

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();  
    }

    private byte[] GetPdfBytes()
    {
        string pdfFileFullName = @"C:\Reports\Test.pdf";
        //TODO: you can fetch the bytes from database as well and return. i have used pdf file.
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFileFullName);
    }
```

Comment: I managed to solved the problem where I need to put the response.clear before response.contentype.